# CoreData - copy model to Documents folder?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a project that uses Core Data.

When the app runs for the first time, do I have to copy the model to the Documents folder, so that the user can make changes?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly.

if you are starting out with a pre-existing dataset, you can include the default dataset in the app bundle, and copy it to the document directory, where it will be writable.

however if it is starting as an empty store, it will automatically be created in the right place in the current Xcode templates.